# XCode 6 : error when selecting a view with its storyboard ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

This is the code :

```
let first = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstView")  as! UIViewController
let second = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondView")  as! UIViewController
```

The first line is OK.
The second line produces an error :

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I've checked that I was **using the correct storyboard ID** one thousand times, I have copied and pastes it, rewritten it and everything. The problem is elsewhere.

What are the other parameters that may cause the error ?

Comment: It is working fine with me... Try cleaning the project cmd+shift+k

Comment: and your storyboard optional is correctly initialized?

Comment: Look at the two lines of code : the first line is OK, the second causes an error. So the error comes from somewhere else. The problem is I don't know where to search it.